# Fixing items in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, replace, iteration

Suppose I have a dictionary that has items that need to be parsed or 'fixed' in some way:

```
testDict = {'05071': ['Clarksville*050112', 'Coal Hill*050315', 'Hartman*050251', 'Johnson County*050441'], '41067': ['Beaverton ***410240', 'Forest Grove ***410241', 'Hillsboro ***410243', 'King City ***410269', 'North Plains ***410270', 'Sherwood ***410273', 'Tualatin ***410277'],...}
```

I want to replace any of the value list items that have " ***" with "*":

```
for k, v in testDict.items():
  for item in v:
    if " ***" in item:
        item = item.replace(" ***", "*")
```

That would return, for example an item: `'Sherwood*450184'` instead of `'Sherwood ***410273'`. My question now is, how do I replace the old `item` with the new `item` in `testDict`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either:

1. Use [a `list` comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) to create a new `list` and use it to replace the contents of `v` all at once, or
2. [Use `enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get indices as well as items, allowing index assignment to update `v` item by item

The former is pretty easy:

```
for k, v in testDict.items():
    # Replaces unconditionally, but that's fine, since it's a no-op otherwise
    v[:] = [item.replace(" ***", "*") for item in v]
```

Assigning to `v[:]` replaces the entire contents of `v` with the newly constructed `list` (which is then thrown away). The `[:]` is necessary; without it, you'd just rebind `v` to a new `list`, but the only `list` would be unchanged.

The latter is a smaller change to the code:

```
for k, v in testDict.items():
    for i, item in enumerate(v):  # Get indices as we go
        if " ***" in item:
            v[i] = item.replace(" ***", "*")  # Assign to index in v
```

Optionally, if you need to use `item` for other purposes, you can do:

```
            v[i] = item = item.replace(" ***", "*")  # Assign to index in v
```

so you can continue to use the new value of `item` without repeatedly indexing `v`.

Note that the list comprehension isn't strictly necessary for approach #1 (you could just make a brand new `list` by manual `append`s in whatever way you like, then do `v[:] = newlist`), but it's a lot cleaner looking and obvious that `v`'s contents are being swapped for a simple transform of the original `v`.

Comment: Side-note: Given this is Python 2.7, I'd recommend changing your top-level `for` loop from `for k, v in testDict.items():` to `for k, v in testDict.viewitems():` (or `iteritems`, I just tend to use `viewitems` by default to precisely match Py3 behavior). On Python 2, iterating plain `.items()` must eagerly construct a brand new `list` containing a shallow copy of the key/value pairs, iterate it, then discard it when the loop completes; `.iteritems()`/`.viewitems()` iterate a live view of the underlying `dict` with fixed overhead, no matter the size of the `dict`.

Comment: I chose your solution because I liked the list comprehension; shortest and simplest. I also found  other instances or `***` that needed to be replaced (random spaces or more *'s) and that was the best fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
for k, v in testDict.items():
  for i, item in enumerate(v):
    if " ***" in item:
        v[i] = item.replace(" ***", "*")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `item` variable holds just a copy of the value of each item in `testDict`, so assigning `item` with a different value will have no effect on the corresponding item in `testDict`. You should assign a new value to `testDict` by indices instead:

```
for k, v in testDict.items():
    for i, item in enumerate(v):
        if " ***" in item:
            v[i] = item.replace(" ***", "*")
```